# Get an input of array using Getoptions in perl

Tags: perl, getopt

I am trying to get create a file in perl using Getoptions and one of the input is an array. My code looks like this:

```
my $filename = 'grid.sh';
my @job_name;
my $output_file;
my $testbench;
my %opts = (
 'job_name' => \@job_name,
 'output' => \$output_file,
 'testbench' => \$testbench,
);
GetOptions(
  \%opts,
 'job_name=s',
'output=s',
'testbench=s'
);
open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open";
for (my $i=0; $i <= 2; $i++) {
print $fh "Job names are $job_name[$i]";
}
   close $fh;
```

in my command line I am providing the input as

```
perl grip_script.pl "-job_name test -job_name test1 -job_name test2"
```

But the file is not giving the right data. Can you please tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: 'Unmatched right curly bracket' is a copy/paste error? And you are Using GetOpt::Long I presume.

Comment: Ya sorry about that. It was a copy/paste error. Yes I am using GetOpt::Long

Answer (score 3):

You mistakenly double-quoted your entire list of arguments, thereby making it into a single invalid argument.

Try this instead:

```
perl grip_script.pl --job_name test --job_name test1 --job_name test2
```

As bytepusher suggested, you also need to fix your call to GetOptions:

```
GetOptions(
 'job_name=s' => \@job_name,
 'output' => \$output_file,
 'testbench' => \$testbench,
);
```

With those two changes, I am able to run your test script and get the expected results.

Output:

```
Job names are testJob names are test1Job names are test2
```

Note you are missing a line break in your print statement so all three print calls appear on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Your notation of GetOpts is confusing to me.

Why do you pass in %opts and then more?

Have you tried this?

```
GetOptions(
    'job_name=s' => \@job_name,
'output=s' => \$output_file,
'testbench=s' => \$testbench,
);
```

?

Also, see here in the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Options-with-multiple-values) further examples of multiple values passed in.

Those values only appear if you do not quote in command line, as the other answerer pointed out, so call

```
perl grip_script.pl --job_name test --job_name test2 --job_name test3
```

and for me, they are all in @job_name.

Comment: when I am using the examples you all have mentioned then only my first job which 'test' is showing up. The other two test1 and test2 are not which is the problem.

Comment: hm. Just noticed myself after playing around a little. Lemme get back to you ;)

Comment: Mr. Sam Choukri has it right, with my notation and no quotes, both are in @job_name for me.

Comment: Hey guys I got it working now. Your inputs helped me out. Thanks.